# Training ray.rllib algorithm with vectorized environments

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, ray, rllib

I am working with ray.rllib and I am stuck with using a [static method (line40)](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/rllib/env/vector_env.py) of vectorizing my custom environment and training it using PPOTrainer(). I use the `existing_envs` parameter and hand over a list of gym.envs which I manually create. Is there any option for passing vec envs in PPOTrainer(), can anyone help me out with this?

So in short: how can I train PPO with ray.rllib when I created a Vectorized Env with [static method (line40)](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/rllib/env/vector_env.py).